# Snowflake SQL - Can you use a table alias when the table name is dynamic and you are joining to other tables?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use dynamic SQL with Snowflake and use best practices to avoid SQL Injection (i.e. don't concatenate strings).

This works (using concatenation):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SomeDB.DeleteStuff(
    WorkingTableName string
    )
    returns varchar
    language sql
as
$$
    declare
        rs resultset;
        query varchar default 'DELETE FROM ' || WorkingTableName || ' as WT USING SomeTable as SU WHERE WT.ServiceUserId = SU.ServiceUserId AND SU.DateOfDeath IS NOT NULL;';
    begin
      rs := (execute immediate :query);
      return 'ok';
    end;
$$;
;
```

... but this doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SomeDB.DeleteStuff(
    WorkingTableName string
    )
    returns varchar
    language sql
as
$$
    declare
        rs resultset;
        query varchar default 'DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(?) as WT USING SomeTable as SU WHERE WT.ServiceUserId = SU.ServiceUserId AND SU.DateOfDeath IS NOT NULL;';
    begin
      rs := (execute immediate :query using (WorkingTableName));
      return 'ok';
    end;
$$;
;
```

I get an error:

> [2022-05-27 12:31:20] [42000][904] Uncaught exception of type
> 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 6 at position 13 : SQL compilation error:
> error line 1 at position 63 [2022-05-27 12:31:20] invalid identifier
> 'WT.SERVICEUSERID'

It seems to not apply the "WT" alias to the table when you use `IDENTIFIER(?)` for the table name.

**Is there a way to use IDENTIFIER(?) in a dynamic query that joins to other tables?**

Comment: It's likely related to use a variable as table name, not with its alias.

Comment: Yes. You are right James but my question still stands. If I just use "DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(?) as WT" in the second example it works. It is as soon as I try to connect to the second table I get the error.

Comment: @MarkRobinson [Snowflake IDENTIFIER() not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71269455/5070879)

Comment: @MarkRobinson For this case rewritting as: `query varchar default 'DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(?) WHERE ServiceUserId IN (SELECT SU.SERVICEUSERID FROM SomeTable  AS SU WHERE SU.DateOfDeath IS NOT NULL);';` will do the trick