# Using an Identifier in a DML statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting an error when I am trying to use identifiers in DML statement.

```
DECLARE
staging_table string;
main_table string;

BEGIN 

SELECT DISTINCT STAGING_TABLE INTO :staging_table FROM SCHEMA.TEST1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'X';
SELECT DISTINCT MAIN_TABLE INTO :main_table FROM SCHEMA.TEST2 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'X'

DELETE FROM identifier(:main_table) AS TRGT 
    USING identifier(:staging_table) AS STG
    WHERE TRGT.COLUMN_ID = STG.COLUMN_ID;

END;
```

ERROR:invalid identifier 'TRGT.COLUMN_ID' (line 14)

Comment: You already have the correct syntax in you DELETE statement, you need to change your SELECT statements to use the same syntax. It's documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding

Comment: @NickW Any idea if we can use a column name as an identifier similar to how I have used a table name. So that I can use that identifier in my where clause. If yes what would be the where clause syntax. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes - the syntax is the same e.g. SELECT max(database_name) into :db_name from identifier(:table_name) WHERE identifier(:column_name) > '2023-05-01';

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use `DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(?) ... USING IDENTIFIER(?) WHERE ...`

Related: [Snowflake IDENTIFIER() not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264209/snowflake-identifier-not-always-working)

---

Workaround by using `DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(?) WHERE col IN (SELECT col FROM IDENTIFIER(?) ...)`

```
DECLARE
  staging_table string;
  main_table string;

BEGIN 

  SELECT DISTINCT STAGING_TABLE INTO :staging_table 
  FROM SCHEMA.TEST1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'X';

  SELECT DISTINCT MAIN_TABLE INTO :main_table 
  FROM SCHEMA.TEST2 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'X'

  DELETE FROM identifier(:main_table)
  WHERE COLUMN_ID IN (SELECT src.COLUMN_ID 
                      FROM identifier(:staging_table) AS src
                      WHERE src.COLUMN_ID IS NOT NULL);
  RETURN 'Success';
END;
```

---

Minimal Reproducible Example for Snowflake Scripting Block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test1(ID) AS SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test2(ID) AS SELECT 2;

SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
-- 7.17.0

DECLARE 
   A STRING := 'TEST1';
   B STRING := 'TEST2';

BEGIN
    DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(:A) AS TARGET
    USING IDENTIFIER(:B) AS TMP
    WHERE TARGET.ID = TMP.ID;
    
    RETURN 'Success';
END;
-- invalid identifier 'TARGET.ID' (line 8)


DECLARE 
   A STRING := 'TEST1';
   B STRING := 'TEST2';

BEGIN
    DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER(:A)
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT SRC.ID FROM IDENTIFIER(:B) AS SRC WHERE src.ID IS NOT NULL);

    RETURN 'Success';
END;
-- 'Success';
```